# Azure AD ClaimsMappingPolicy Claims Conditions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to create a custom claims mapping policy that will **emit claims based on conditions** (similar to what can be done via the portal [like this)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM).  I've seen the documentation on how to create claims mapping policies via the Graph API, but cannot find info on how to set conditions.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Through Graph API , You can use claims-mapping policies to:

- Select which claims are included in tokens
- Create claim types that do
  not already exist
- Choose or change the source of data emitted in
  specific claims

Please see the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/claimsmappingpolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image]

But you can achieve the same through using Customize claims through the powershell command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping

Hope this helps,

thanks

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'm specifically trying to emit claims based on conditions.  While the claims mapping policy does allow you to create claims, I can't seem to find a way to define a policy that includes conditional claims.

Comment: Have you checked this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#use-a-claims-transformation-in-tokens

Comment: I see.  So you suggest I use a Claims Transformation instead of a claims condition.  That might actually be a better alternative, I will give that a try.  Thank you!